# How can I calculate total for different grouping variables?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dataframes. How can I calculate totals (sum) per  `kind`  for all of the columns. And then having number  `column`  to be a  `'total'`

```
ONE={'kind':['clear','clean','light','dark','sweet'],
       'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18, 19],
   'number':['one','one','one','one','one']}

TWO={'kind':['clear','clean','light', 'sweet', 'middle'],
       'Age':[22, 1, 12, 18,40],
   'number':['two','two','two','two','two']}
THREE={'kind':['light','dark','sweet','clean','clear'],
       'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18, 100],
   'number':['three','three','three','three','three']}
ONE= pd.DataFrame(ONE)
TWO= pd.DataFrame(TWO)
THREE = pd.DataFrame(THREE)
mydf = ONE.append(TWO).append(THREE)
```

Output to be like

```
kind    Age      number
clear   sum(Age) total
clean   sum(Age) total
light   sum(Age) total
dark    sum(Age) total
sweet   sum(Age) total
```

.....same as mydf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `number` column to get 'total' in terms of the numeric values of `one`, `two`, `three`, you can do it this way:

```
mydf.assign(number=mydf['number'].map({'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3})).groupby('kind', as_index=False).sum()
```

Result:

```
     kind  Age  number
0   clean   40       6
1   clear  142       6
2    dark   39       4
3   light   51       6
4  middle   40       2
5   sweet   56       6
```

Here, `one`, `two`, `three` are treated as 1, 2, 3 respectively.

We use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the strings to numeric values before summing them up.

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby()` method:

```
result=mydf.groupby('kind').agg(Age =('Age','sum'),number=('number','count'))
```

Now If you print `result` you will get your desired output:

```
       Age  number
kind        
clean   40      3
clear   142     3
dark    39      2
light   51      3
middle  40      1
sweet   56      3
```

### Update:

Alternate way:

```
result=mydf.groupby('kind').agg({'Age':'sum','number':'count'})
```

If needed use `reset_index()` method:

```
result=result.reset_index()
```

Comment: I have an error: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

Comment: what is your `pandas` version?

Comment: Updated answer...Kindly have a look **:)**